# Testing UserPassesTestMixin with django test client

Tags: python, django, integration-testing

I've protected a django class-based view with the UserPassesTestMixin.  Its test_func takes a parameter called division and checks whether the current user is the head of that division.

The view works perfectly in the site but I've been unable to write a successful test. It seems that between the client.get and the test_func, the user is disappearing.

I've tried this with RequestFactory and Client.  I've tried forcing login. Made sure the correct middleware is in place.

The tests for the mixin didn't help me see the issue. ( https://github.com/django/django/blob/29f607927fe82e2c8baab171dfa8baf710cd9b83/tests/auth_tests/test_mixins.py )

Now I'm stuck with no way to test various roles against the  views protected by UserPassesTestMixin.  I'd appreciate any insight as to why, when I login using **client.login(username='div1chair', password='basicpassword')**, there's an empty **self.request.user** in the view itself.

```
def test_permissions_to_access_division_summary_view(self):
        """
        This test ensures that only department chairs and the division
        director for the specific division detail can see the division
        summary.
        """
        url = "/division1"

        client = Client()
        client.login(username='div1chair', password='basicpassword')

        # ipdb here confirms that div1chair is logged in
        # ETA: ut oh.  looks like this is not accurate. Now I'm really confused. client.login is giving False.

        response = client.get(url,follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) # AssertionError: 404 != 200
```

Here is the view I'm testing.

```
class DivisionDirectorView(UserPassesTestMixin, View):

    def test_func(self):     

        division = Division.objects.get(short_name=self.kwargs['division'])

        # ipdb here confirms that there is no user, or at least username is ''
        if self.request.user == division.director:
            return True

        return False
```

ETA: here is the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from fds.apps.professionalmetrics import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.metrics_default, name='metrics_default'),
    # SNIP
    url(r'(?P<division>[\w-]+)/$',
        views.DivisionDirectorView.as_view(),
        name='div-metric-summary'),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test_func` and `dispatch` methods are unusual - the `test_func` for the `UserPassesTest` mixin should not take any arguments except `self`.  I would simplify the `test_func` to the following:

```
def test_func(self):     
    division = Division.objects.get(short_name=self.kwargs['division'])
    return self.request.user == division.director
```

Then you should be able to remove the custom code from the `dispatch` method.

However, I'm not sure whether that will fix the problem you are finding in your test. You haven't shown your urls, so I can't tell whether `client.get(url, follow=True)` should return `200` or whether 404 is expected. You could try debugging by setting `follow = False`, and inspecting the `response`.

Comment: Thank you, Alasdair!  I have simplified the test_func code as you suggest and it works great. I'm still mystified why when the test logs in using client.login(username='div1chair', password='basicpassword'), there's an empty self.request.user in the view itself. I've attached the urls.py, though my guess is that isn't it.  The test_func is failing because self.request.user is empty. I appreciate your comment!

Comment: How do you know that `client.login(...)` is successful? Have you checked to make sure it returns `True`? I don't see how `/division1` from your test is meant to match any of the urls you have posted.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks.  The problem was that I needed to force login.  I tried that earlier but somehow did it incorrectly.  Also, apologies for snipping out the wrong part of urls.py.  I'll update the question, although as it turns out, forcing login solved it.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Finally, note that your `url = "/division1"` is missing the trailing slash. The test passes at the moment because you have `follow=True`, but it's fragile. Ideally, you want `client.get(url, follow=False)`, then you can be confident that the status_code 200 isn't from the client following a redirect to the login page from the `UserPassesTestMixin`.